# How to draw line in each widget in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, draw

I'm trying to show binary tree on labels. How can I draw lines inside each label from the center to the right and left edges? The task is very strange, I understand, but you i need to display a self-written tree with the most basic Kivy objects. Kivy trees cannot be used. All solutions on the Internet are only for the touchscreen.

In this loop i add labels with node value, if node is not found it is 0

```
class TreeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=5, spacing=5)
            for i in range(maxdepth):
                inside_bl = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
                for j in range(2 ** i):
                    try: inside_bl.add_widget(Label01(text=str(mx_lvl[i][j]),color=(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)))
                    except: inside_bl.add_widget(Label111(text="0",color=(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)))
                bl.add_widget(inside_bl)
        return bl
```

Here i tried to make class label01. I thought using self. will create its own line for each label and draw relative to the origin or center of the label.

```
class Label01(Label):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Label01,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            self.pos = self.pos
            Color(0,1,0,1)
            self.line= Line(points=(self.x+100,self.y+100,self.x+250,self.y+250),close = True)
```

Likewise for label 111. I thought using self. will create its own unique line for each label and draw relative to the origin or center of the label.

- tree.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
<Label111>:
    canvas.before:
        Line:
            
            width: 2
            points: (self.x, self.y+50, self.x+200, self.y+100, self.x+300, self.y+200)
        Color:
            rgb: (0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9)
```

- main.py:

```
class Label111(Label):
    pass
```

I thought that when using self. i will get a test line inside each label (31 in total) but i got only 2 lines at the bottom of the window. Question: How do I draw two lines inside each label relative to its center?
[image: Window with only two lines]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are drawing the lines for `Label01` in its `__init__()` method, all the lines are drawn before the position and size of the `Label01` are set. So all the lines are drawn using the default position of the `Label01`, which is (0,0). Since you are doing this in the python code, there is no binding to adjust the lines when the position of the `Label01` is changed.

This can be fixed by either writing your own bindings to do the adjustments, or by letting `kv` do it for you by defining the lines in `kv`. Like this:

```
<Label01>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Line:
            points: self.center_x,self.center_y,self.center_x+250,self.center_y+250
```

The points are defined relative to the center of the `Label01` (as you mentioned), and then the definition for `Label01` becomes simply:

```
class Label01(Label):
    pass
```